# gulp build throwing off quotes that add active class in HTML using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, build, gulp

Using gulp-angular yeoman generator.

I wrote out this line to set an anchor to receive an active class.

```
 <a ui-sref='landing.recipe' ng-click="land.select('one')"           
   ng-class="{active: land.selected === 'one'}">Recipe</a>
```

obviously there is some javascript on the controller, but when I serve local it works fine.

The problem is, after I run gulp build it did this and no longer functions,

```
<a ui-sref="landing.recipe" ng-click="land.select(" one")"="" 
  ng-class="{active: land.selected === " one"}"="" href="#/landing/recipe">Recipe</a>
```

thanks for any help with how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the inputs from strings to real numbers to eliminate quotes in quotes and it works perfect now.

pre build,

```
 <a ui-sref='landing.recipe' ng-click='land.select(1)'               
 ng-class='{active: land.selected === 1}'>Recipe</a>
```

after build,

```
<a ui-sref="landing.recipe" ng-click="land.select(1)" 
ng-class="{active: land.selected === 1}" href="#/landing/recipe" class="active">Recipe</a>
```

everything works now post build.